# How to conver strace -o >(cat >>outputfile) command [args] ... to csh

Tags: bash, csh, strace

I have the following command on bash terminal that works great:

```
strace -o >(cat >>outputfile) command [args] ...
```

the command appends the output file of strace.
How can I get the same when using csh terminal?

Thanks.

Comment: use `strace -Ao outputfile command [args]`  instead!!

Comment: not possible with CSH, you have to split it in two: `strace -o tmpfile command [args] ...; cat tmpfile >> outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down this command using `man bash`. The difficulty seems to be the notation:

```
>(cat >> outputfile)
```

This is what is called process-substitution:

> Process  substitution allows a process's input or output to be referred to using
> a filename.  It takes the form of <(list) or >(list).  The process list  is  run
> asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename.  This filename is
> passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion.  If
> the  >(list)  form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list. <snip>

So what this says is that `>(cat >> outputfile)` represents a filename, but the data that is written to that file is input to the command `cat >> outputfile` which just appends the output of `strace` to `output`. This can be replaced by

```
strace -Ao outputfile command [args]
```

> **`-A`, `--output-append-mode`**: Open the file provided in the `-o` option in append mode.

Comment: True however, I cant use strace version 5. I got version version 4.12